# C++ I don't understand my exceptions what() behavior

Tags: c++, exception

I'm writing a exception class with a what() method.

```
const char* what() const throw() {
    return "test";
}
```

works fine, but

```
const char* what() const throw() {
    return (std::string("test")).c_str();
}
```

seems to return a random result. Why?

Comment: What do you think happens when `(std::string("test")).c_str();` goes out of scope?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::string("test")` creates a *temporary* string object. `c_str` returns a pointer to some internal storage of that temporary object. After the function exits, that’s a dangling pointer – it points to invalid memory.

There is no way to circumvent this. You either have to make your string object more long-lived by declaring (and initialising, since the function is `const`) it outside the function – or you need to manually allocate heap storage inside the function, copy the string there, and return a pointer to that storage. However, this is complicated, error-prone, and violates the contract of the function, because the user of your error class doesn’t expect to free memory.

In fact, here’s a simple implementation of an error class (toy, since I don’t know your use-case) with this in mind:

```
struct my_logic_error : std::logic_error {
    // `std::logic_error` already overrides `what`, we only need to initialise it!
    my_logic_error(int errcode) :
        std::logic_error{std::string{"Logic error occurred with error code "} +
                std::to_string(errcode)} {}
};
```

Assuming you derive from an exception class without this luxury, your code gets minimally more complex:

```
struct my_error : std::exception {
    my_error(int errcode) :
        message{std::string{"Logic error occurred with error code "} +
                std::to_string(errcode)} {}

    char const* what() const noexcept {
        return message.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string message;
};
```

Comment: I would like to return `(std::string("test")).c_str()`, how to do this?

Comment: @user3561614 As the answer explains: you can't, however much you want to. You must find something else to want.

Comment: So what's the common way to return `IReturnAString() + "test"` here?

Comment: @user3561614: Assuming you have a `std::string` variable, say `mystr`, and you want to return its contents (as opposed to exactly `(std::string("test")).c_str()`), you could copy the string - e.g. using `mycopy = strdup(mystr.c_str())` - and return `mycopy`.

Comment: @psmears This doesn't work, "no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "const char*" exists".

Comment: @user3561614: Are you sure you're calling `mycopy = strdup(mystr.c_str())` and not just `mycopy = strdup(mystr)`? The latter of the two would give an error like the one you report...

Comment: @psmears I did `std::string mycopy` not `const char* mycopy`... But now the caller has to free the memory?

Comment: *Someone* will have to free the memory. The function returns a `char *`, which means you're tied to using C strings and will have to manage the memory somehow. But, in this case at least, it probably shouldn't be the caller - you can (for instance) store the pointer as a member in your exception object, and free it in the destructor.

Comment: Since this is happening in an error class’ `what` function, the correct answer is, simply: *do not do this*. Full stop. Instead, use a member variable of type `std::string` that you have initialised in the constructor, and refer to that member variable inside `what`. Everything else violates the contract of an exception class’ `what` function.

Comment: ... and as @KonradRudolph says, once you're storing it in a member variable, you may as well make the member variable a `std::string` and just use `c_str()` on that (without any `strdup()`). (Sorry, I'd overlooked that this was an `exception::what()` method!)

Comment: The final example is the best solution IMHO .

Answer (score 0):

You store the string value in a member of your exception class, and you return c_str() on this member.

Doing a strdup can work, but the caller must free the memory, that's not a safe way of doing.